# Al Gore won't leave me alone. How do I unfriend him on Facebook?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

In exploring South Park, I met a somewhat curious older gentleman hiding in the bushes over behind the movie theater. It turns out that gentleman was former Vice President [Al Gore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al_Gore). He promptly became my Facebook friend, and asked me to help him place some fancy science equipment around town.

After I did that for him, he (kind of creepily, in retrospect), invited me to his private storage locker on the edge of town.

And now, **he won't leave me alone.**

Every time I take another few steps, I have a new Facebook message from Al Gore. They're all nonsense and I'm tired of them.

I have a quest to remove him from my Facebook friends, but I can't figure out how to do that.

How do I unfriend Al Gore?

Comment: This question appears to be off topic beca-- wait, no, nevermind.

Comment: @CyberSkull I don't want to make him *angry*. I just want him to leave me alone! :(

Comment: Change your address to Texas, and change your profile picture to G W Bush. He'll be too defeated to continue spamming

Comment: One does not simply... eh, I'll spare the additional meme here.

Answer (score 83):

Go back to Al Gore's shed and punch him.  This will initiate a battle, after which he will stop spamming you.

Afterwards, he will still be your friend, even though the quest to remove him has completed.

Comment: "Go back to Al Gore's shed and punch him" Oh man even the answer is classic Arqade lol.

Comment: All right, that's it. I'm getting this game.

Comment: I don't think hitting Al Gore will initiate combat with him. To initiate combat with him, you have to *talk* to him.

Answer (score 6):

When I went to his shed (u-store it - it's the first shed on the left when you get around to the back, facing Mackey's storage shed mmkay) it took me a couple of times to figure out how to actually beat him with his secret service agents.

The way I handled him was fight alongside Cartman. I was a warrior and would constantly do the attack to freeze him and then have Cartman do his fire tricks. When the secret service agents it's good to just take them out as you can and keep healing. I would bring Kyle in momentarily to get my shields and attacks up. I would also do the stomp trick as well to damage all of them....

Comment: Thanks! I [asked the obvious related followup question. I'd encourage you to post this answer there!](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/159121/how-can-i-beat-al-gore-in-a-fight?lq=1)