# How can I beat Al Gore in a fight?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

Okay. So it seems that [the only way to unfriend Al Gore](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/158984/3129) is to beat the crap out of him. Straightforward enough.

Unfortunately, between his boring presentations on Global Warming which put me to sleep, and his trio of *very* well armed and armored Secret Service personnel, I'm finding that easier said than done. Unfortunately, my various adult and supernatural friends, like Mr. Slave, Jesus, Mr. Hanky, and that dude from the Chinese Restaurant, are unwilling to come to my aid. This leaves me in something of a pickle, as Butters would say.

How do I beat up the Vice President before he and his bodyguards kill me?

Comment: the more i read about this game, the more i want it. now.

Comment: I imagine your choice of class makes a huge difference *(I chose fighter, and found this battle really easy)*.  What class are you?

Comment: At what level did you try to confront him?

Comment: It helps if your brother is the governor of Florida.

Answer (score 16):

At first try as lvl 9 thief I got down to 1 special agent and suddenly lost like 100% of my health from the "screwed" effect in one turn, and lost, which sucked since I could have won if I just cured myself.

Each other attempt at battling him went from bad to worse, I would die in 2-3 turns...Which means I was extremely lucky the first time.
So luck and reflexes are the key if you want to win in a head to wall situation, if you don't block everything especially concussion grenade, you will die immediately.

Otherwise if you have enough health/armor to survive few turns, you will need a lot of armor reduction, or spells that ignore armor, also try to kill the agent in the middle first since his concussion grenade is far too dangerous, then 2 other agents and lastly Al Gore.

---

Fortunately I heard of a smarter way to win this, and it is with the use of **Jimmy**. After encountering elves you will be able to select Jimmy to as your partner (which I haven't noticed for quite some time).

Now once you have him in your party you can go battle Al.
After he calls reinforcements use Jimmy's **"lullaby" spell** as soon as you can, if you succeed this will put asleep 3 agents leaving you to fight just Al Gore, and pick off agents one by one.
And make sure to use his **"Power chord" ability** before each lullaby, in order to restore your PP so you can always have enough for Lullaby.

Comment: This is the strategy I used to beat them. Make sure you there are no status affects that will cause damage to the sleeping people as it will wake them up.

Answer (score 8):

Stock up on speed potions - If you have the cash to buy a supply of the speed+attack coffee from the Twitch Bros shop, do so, but you'll want all the speed potions you can carry. You'll probably have a sufficient supply of PP restoring potions, but they are also fairly useful, so ensure you have plenty.

First important point, get the timing on blocking the global warming presentation correct. The screwed status it inflicts is largely ignorable (This fight will *not* last 99 turns, one way or another), but the sleep is utterly debilitating.

The secret to beating heavily armored foes who are beyond your ability to defeat normally, I've found, is to control the flow of battle as much as is humanly possible. Unfortunately, being a boss - Al Gore is immune to some of the best statuses to achieve this. So, every turn drink a speed potion to attack twice. Your buddy, however, should probably be feeding you PP restoration items on his turn.

Use your best Defense Down abilities on your first two attacks against Gore. And follow that up with as much damage and DoT as you can - stacking bleed is awesome if you can do it efficiently. Ideally, once he summons his guards he should be almost dead, to the point where the DoT will finish him off in a turn or two so that you can ignore him.

Lastly, block everything! It sounds obvious, but blocking everything can mean the difference between the guards killing you in one round and two rounds. And two rounds means you have an opportunity to heal. Granted, getting the timing right can be tricky sometimes.

### Equipment

Ultimately, what you're wearing and wielding is up to you (Although I recommend at least one of your weapons have an AoE component), but some of the patches/strap-ons are considerably more useful than others.

For weapons (try to avoid any that are already covered by your abilities):

- Ice Damage is one of the best things you have, IMHO, as it applies **slow** to enemies, giving you more free hits (bosses may be immune to slow, I can't remember).
- Bleed can stack up to 5 times dealing devastating DoT, no matter what their armor is.
- Fire and Gross for additional DoT.

Armor:

- Have at least one patch that grants PP, go for the one that is likely to be triggered most often.
- The rest are up to you - If you're a fighter, then you may want a +armor patch, because some of your abilities do more damage based on armor, but I honestly find most of the patches lack-luster, providing very little benefit.

### Buddies

I found Butters to be the best for this fight; keep using his basic attack until the guards are summoned and then use Professor Chaos. All of the attacks on Professor Chaos's wheel are powerful, but what I found the most useful was the shield, as it gives some much needed breathing room against these well-armed foes.

Kenny's unicorn summon is another great ability; massive damage and bleed - although my success rate for the QTE is about 75%, and being down an ally for a few turns means *all* the damage is directed at you.

If they are available to you at this point, Jimmy might be able to temporarily sleep the guards, allowing you to focus on Gore, and deal with one enemy at a time. Stan's in-combat buddy command can lower an opponent's defense while still allowing him to attack.

As I mentioned, controlling the flow of battle is critical when you are outclassed. So if your buddy's health is critical, consider switching them out. If they drink a speed potion, they can attack on the first turn and switch out on the second. And even without a speed potion - it saves you from needing to revive them on the next turn - and the switched in buddy has full HP and PP if they haven't been used yet.

Answer (score 3):

I finally beat him as a level 8 thief.  I suck at twitch so nothing relying on defense worked for me. What did was:

1- Speed potions for double attacks (backstab on Gore and mug on a guard)

2- First Butters attack: Prof. Chaos (I suck at twitch so I just hoped for one of the 2 helpful attacks: the chaos hammer that stuns them all for one round, or the shield, but if you're good at twitch, go for the shield)

3- After Butters 1st round, he should feed you with a power potion each round until he's very hurt, then bring Kenny (I only had Kenny and Butters).

4- Use Kenny's Unicorn on middle row (guard + Gore). Gore should go down from this by this point.

5- As soon as Gore goes down, do keep the middle guard stunned. Better if you can pull a double attack with stuns on him and another guard.

After this it was just mop up.

Answer (score 3):

I just beat this boss last night as a level 9 warrior. Took me a few tries to get this right though. First you need to block that "boring presentation" attack. DON'T LOOK at the screen and instead focus on your characters and you will see the opportunity to block the sleep/screwed attack. After that:

1. Try and get burn status on the boss as well as 5 bleed (and maybe grossed out if you can manage it) so that he'll continue to drain HP even after his buddies show up (believe me that damage over time will inflict more than your attacks). Customize your weapons so you can accomplish this.
2. Once his cronies show up, get burn status on all of them too. If you're using speed potions each round, you should be a be able to hit two per round. You can also
3. Once all the buddies are defeated, as a warrior you can use the Charge attack to lower the boss's defense making him much easier to hit.

The idea here is nail those timed hits when it comes to blocking. Using large health potions to keep alive helps a great deal as well. Best of luck (if you haven't beaten him already).

Answer (score 3):

I finally beat him using Stan. You have to keep Al Gore bleeding and on fire, and Grossed out if possible, so add those "strap-ons" to your weapons."

Stock up on Speed potions, Large Health Potions, Revive Potions and make sure you have a few Power Potions and Cure Potions.

Make sure that all your weapons have as many add-ons and your costume as many patches as possible.  You want to be as armored as you can.  You and your buddy are going to have to revive each other for several rounds--four strong attacks will take out one of you.  Focus on keeping up the health of at least one of you .  Also, when you get a chance, buy the Perk that makes sure that Revival Potions give you FULL POINTS!

First thing, give your friend a Cure potion, to wake them up!

The Secret Service agents all have high defenses, at first, you will literally take off 1 of their many points for each attack (their points go up with your level, at level ten, the two lower Secret Service had over 1200 points and the highest one had over 2400), there are various special attacks that take down defenses.  I used the Circum-Scythe attack first on each one (my character is a Jew.), then attacked with either Missile of Slowing or Longsword (both with fire additions).  Then Stan used his sword (twice, with Speed Potion).  Butters' hammer didn't seem to work as well, although several people have reported beating Al Gore with Butters as a buddy.

Start with the lower agents and focus your attacks, make sure one is down before you start on the next (This is a good tip in general!).  Finish with Al Gore.  I read on a forum that you have to keep him bleeding, and he does go down relatively fast (300-400 points per round, he starts at over 5000 for a level 10 player).  In the first round, try get Al Gore on fire and/or bleeding.  He will still keep regenerating points, but not as many. Once you focus on him, you want to make sure he doesn't regenerate more points (about a quarter of his HP, I think) than you're taking off of him.

It took me at LEAST 20 tries, probably more to get through this fight.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I beat him as a level 11 Jew and I used Cartman as my buddy.

First I would use Circum-scythe to apply 2 stacks of Bleed and Defense Down, then use the curses of Cartman which deal massive electric damages.

When his mobs showed, I used Plague of Egypt and called the frogs rain, the fire rain and the crickets then I used the second spell of Cartman (don't remember the name) to deal massive fire damage to everyone.

From this point I spammed Sling of David and curses to get rid of him.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option to use Kyle as your partner use him, I couldn't beat Al Gore without him.
Use Kyles 16pp attack and also use lots of speed potions they help a lot...
This was even harder then the nazi zombie Kenny boss.

Answer (score -1):

Nagasaki = 1 hit death kill easy

Answer (score -2):

Do a perfect Nagasaki and you can beat him in one hit.